# Why android build-tools packed some SDK's classes into an apk?

Tags: android

As we all know, every Android ROM contains all the classes in android.jar which is in android SDK.

[image]

I mean you can find all SDK's classes in your mobile at framework.jar or framework.dex(which is decompile from /system/framework/arm/boot.oat).

But today I found some SDK's classes also packed into my apk file, like "View","ViewGroup":

[image]

I don't understand, If a ROM/OS already have all the classes that an apk needed, why build-tools packed all the classes into an apk?
What's the function of framework.jar(or framework.dex) in a ROM?

Comment: Have you find out anything? Moreover it takes some space.